# Code isn't plotting level 0 of a factor in ggplot's geom_bar()

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-bar

My final plot doesn't show 0 level from factor A.

Header data:

```
month  A           B
mayo   20           6.9
mayo   16          16.3
mayo   14          19.8
mayo   12          12.6
mayo    9          19.5
mayo    8          65.4
mayo   18          11.7
mayo   17          22.8
mayo   15          34.3
mayo   13          36.9
mayo   11          43.7
mayo   10          21.6
mayo   21          20.9
mayo    7           7.3
mayo   22          32.3
mayo   19          17.8
mayo    0          96.0
```

Structure of the data.frame:

```
'data.frame':   17 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ month          : chr  "mayo" "mayo" "mayo" "mayo" ...
 $ A         : Factor w/ 18 levels "0","7","8","9",..: 15 11 9 7 4 3 13 12 10 8 ...
 $ B: num  6.9 16.3 19.8 12.6 19.5 65.4 11.7 22.8 34.3 36.9 ...
```

My R code for ggplotting:

```
ggplot(data,aes(x = A, y = B))  +
        geom_bar(stat="identity",size=1.5,colour = "black",fill="green")
```

**UPDATE**

It has been a problem with my R code. Level 0 is included in month == "mayo", not for month =="abril" (included in full data).

Indeed, it doesn't show 0 level:

```
ggplot(data[data$month=="abril",],aes(x = A, y = B))  +
            geom_bar(stat="identity",size=1.5,colour = "black",fill="green")
```

Thanks

Comment: Could you provide the data, or some code that produces the data?

Comment: Please clarify your problem: What exactly is missing from the plot?

Comment: @ThomasK this code graphs all bars correspond to all levels except 0

Comment: @MarioM. Using the data you provided yields a plot with a bar of height 96 at `x = 0`. Maybe there is something missing form what you are sharing, so possibly use `dput`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems to work for me

```
data <- data.frame(month=rep('mayo',17),
           A=factor(c(20,16,14,12,9,8,18,17,15,13,11,10,21,7,22,19,0)),
           B=c(6.9,16.3,19.8,12.6,19.5,65.4,11.7,22.8,34.3,36.9,43.7,21.6,20.9,7.3,32.3,17.8,96.0),
           stringsAsFactors = F)

ggplot(data,aes(x = A, y = B))  +
  geom_bar(stat="identity",size=1.5,colour = "black",fill="green")

str(data)
```

Structure of data.frame

```
'data.frame':   17 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ month: chr  "mayo" "mayo" "mayo" "mayo" ...
 $ A    : Factor w/ 17 levels "0","7","8","9",..: 15 11 9 7 4 3 13 12 10 8 ...
 $ B    : num  6.9 16.3 19.8 12.6 19.5 65.4 11.7 22.8 34.3 36.9 ...
```

There's something about the structure of the data.frame.. In the case you posted you have 18 factor levels.. for 17 observations?

Comment: it works. 17 observations because I show only the data header. In str() I consider full data. thanks

Comment: @MarioM. you could mark it as the chosen solution. That way jg_r will get his reward in points

Comment: @MarioM Aha i see why. Cheers mario! :)